# Who should the moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderators, voting

### [Guidelines](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153/moderator-nominations)

- Use this thread. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user's profile so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by commenting on (or indeed editing) the answer.
- Vote on users you feel will make **[good Moderator candidates](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)**. **Please be civil and respectful.**

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community development; members who:

- Are currently a registered user in good standing.
- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Exhibit patience and fairness at all times in their questions, answers, and comments.
- Lead by example, showing respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Want the responsibility. Moderators volunteer a lot of time and work. Its can be hugely rewarding experience but it isn't always a popularity contest.

Bonus points for:

- Being the site proposer or heavily involved in the proposal process.
- Members who referred a lot of followers/committees on Area 51.
- Members with participation in *both* meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).

These users will be contacted and three of them will be selected to act as Moderators until the formal elections.

They will:

- Have access to the tools to perform the duties of Moderation
- Have access to a special chat room where they will collectively work through the challenges of moderation and community self-policing with the Stack Exchange team
- Drive the process of selecting the site's attributes (domain names, design issues, the FAQ, etc.)
- Help get publicity for their sites and organize their communities

Basically, **they will have the ear of the Stack Exchange team for anything they can do to help this site succeed.** They will act as a liaison — a job that "links" Stack Overflow with this community.

Moderators solve a basic scalability problem. The SE team can't be in each site, identifying the issues and helping each community grow. That's where Moderators come in; they make sure communities are enabled to solve these problems where they can and elicit help when necessary.

Comment: Don't you think it's a little soon to ask that?

Comment: The question will there when you need it.

Comment: *Chi va piano, va sano; chi va sano, va lontano.* : He who goes softly, goes safely; he who goes safely, goes far.

Comment: how are moderators chosen?

Comment: @calavera: By the community. Typically foundation members, active members, etc.

Comment: thanks.  but how does the physical process work?  does some kind of separate voting system open up?

Comment: @calavera: Nominate in an answer, and people will comment (discuss) and upvote / downvote.

Comment: so then how does someone actually have the moderator flag set on their profile?  is there some meta-moderator that does it? :P

Comment: @calavera: If the gaming SE site is any indication, the SE staff will select someone (or some people) they think is appropriate from the nominations as "temporary" mods. Eventually, public elections will be held, and those (I believe) will be done as they are on the Stack Overflow sites: With actual voting, separate from the Q&A system.

Comment: @John Rudy: Thank you!

Comment: I just submitted some heavy edits, mostly from [another excellent post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/211/moderator-nominations). I still feel it is far too early to ask, however since it has been asked we might as well make it complete.

Comment: I removed the self-nomination line, but did not add anything specifically restricting it.

Comment: @calavera: I don't see why you explicitly removed the invitation to self-nominate that every other system had. What's wrong with someone offering to help the community? Then everyone votes. Now you don't have nearly enough candidates to consider. Oh, well. I'll do my best to find suitable candidates.

Comment: @Robert Cartaino: see the answer below where we were discussing self-nomination.  If you think it should be added back in, go for it, it's community wiki after all.  Probably should start a new topic though and get a consensus since now we have conflicting opinions.

Comment: @calavera: *:"If you think it should be added back in..."* No, I'm good. It's your election to hold as you see fit. 'Just offering a dissenting opinion and pointing out the pitfalls.

Comment: @Robert Cartaino: when will the public elections be held?

Comment: @calavera: We're pushing to start nominations around the 30th day after beta "graduation." The voting software is ready. The tough part is figuring out how to hold fair and impartial *nominations*.

Answer (score 4):

I know he's not even here yet, but Kyle Cronin might be a good candidate.  He was the original site proposer, and has been active on other sites, including SuperUser, specifically in the Mac space:
https://superuser.com/users/6/kyle-cronin

Comment: And I *think* he's only a mod on Meta.SO right now, so it's not like we're adding to someone who's overworked.

Comment: I'd love to do it. I do apologize for my absence on the site - I've had DSL problems at home and have been unable to visit during work, and I'm going to be away for the next few days as well, but I hope to make up for the lost time after that.

Comment: @John Meta.SO and Gadgets.SE, but the latter is (sadly) likely going to be killed and merged into this site and an Android site.

Answer (score 3):

I nominate Chealion.  He/she (doesn't specify in their user profile, but I'll use he from here on out based on an educated statistical guess :) ) seems to be pretty open-minded, active, and easy-going.  He provides good answers, and doesn't seem to spam for points (most of his answers have been upvoted multiple times or accepted outright).

He also makes good comments, and provides lots of votes, which I think is a good sign of someone who would make a great moderator.

Comment: Still a he last I checked. :-) Thanks for the nomination. We'll see how things play out during the public beta.

Comment: No problem *sir* :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it on gaming, I'll do it here too: I'm putting my hat in the ring. I'd be happy to help, but also just fine deferring to whomever the community nominates.

Comment: -1, you really shouldn't be self nominating.

Comment: I agreed with Josh K, but doesn't the third line of your post said "Self nominations are okay." ?

Comment: @Studer: It's not mine, it's someone elses that I simply moved in here because I felt it was the best there was. I feel differently, though didn't want to edit the original simply because my views are different. I let my votes display my views.

Comment: Josh, maybe you should put a comment on the OP then, rather than downvoting John's self-nomination.  Poor guy was just following instructions :)

Comment: FWIW I agree, nominations should ideally come from others.  But self-nomination is no big deal I think, since you can see that it tends to have the opposite effect :)

Comment: @Josh K: That was not a big deal. I simply found this funny. I see  that you remove the "self nomination" clause and I agree with this.

Comment: @Studer: I actually didn't, that was **calavera**. He beat me to it.